# C# DataGridView throws exception when removing object from BindingList

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Everything was working fine, until I ran this code:

```
TicketLine tl = (TicketLine)dgTicketLines.SelectedRows[0].DataBoundItem;
tl.Items--;
if (tl.Items < 1)
    CurrentTicket.TicketLines.Remove(tl);
```

CurrentTicket.TicketLines is a `BindingList<TicketLine>`

I get several IndexOutOfRange exceptions in the DataGridView when running the above code.

Comment: What line throws the exception? I'm having a similar issue but the `IndexOutOfRange` exception is thrown when accessing the `DataBoundItem` property.

Answer (score 0):

Take an `ObservableCollection<TicketLine>` instead of the BindingList and it should work.

Comment: What is the difference and whats the problem with BindingList?

Comment: @OMGKurtNilsen: The ObservableCollection implements the IObservable pattern and propagades events when items were added or deleted. The DataGrid listens to that and will remove those lines (or add new ones).

Comment: Actually the problem goes away when I no longer refresh the DGW on list changes.

Comment: The DataGridView should refresh itself when the DataSource has changed. (It will with the ObservableCollection<>)

Comment: It does with a BindingList too. But somehow it thinks there are more items in the list than there are. Doesn't seem like a problem with what collection I use.

Answer (score 0):

You need to suppress the ListChanged event by setting `BindingList<TicketLine>.RaiseListChangedEvents = false;` and then call `BindingList<TicketLine>.ResetBindings();` when you want any changes to get propagated over to the DataGridView. There are other ways of doing this of course, but this has always worked fine for me.